# Coral Dev Board Mini: Cannot read video frame from the Logitech C920 camera

Tags: python, linux-device-driver, webcam, google-coral, mendel-os

I have connected a Logitech C920 camera to the Coral Dev Board Mini:

```sh
mendel@neat-bunny:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
platform:mt8167 (platform:mt8167):
        /dev/video0

14001000.rdma (platform:mt8173):
        /dev/video2

HD Pro Webcam C920 (usb-musb-hdrc.2.auto-1.1):
        /dev/video1
        /dev/video3
```

But cannot read video frame from `/dev/video1` by using python opencv:

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video1')
r, f = cap.read()
```

Here is the dmesg output:
[image]

The last 2 messages are displayed once I have executed the python script.

The blue light was turned on for a moment and then turned off.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this issue still persist ?

Comment: Yes, it does! :/

Comment: Can you add the output of 'v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/video1' to the question?